# JSON not being parsed correctly by Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following code which I'm using to try and parse some JSON into a Scala case class:

```
 val json =
    """{"hits": [
        {"created_at":"2016-02-01T15:01:03.000Z","title":"title","num_comments":778,"parent_id":null,"_tags":["story","author","story_11012044"],"objectID":"11012044","_highlightResult":{"title":{"value":"title","matchLevel":"full","matchedWords":["title"]},"author":{"value":"author","matchLevel":"none","matchedWords":[]},"story_text":{"value":"Please lead","matchLevel":"none","matchedWords":[]}}}
    ]}""".stripMargin

  val jsobj = Json.parse(json)
  val r = (JsPath \ "hits").read[Seq[HiringPost]](Reads.seq[HiringPost])
  val res: JsResult[Seq[HiringPost]] = r.reads(jsobj)
  println("result is: " + res)
```

And some implicits to do the conversion here:

```
case class HiringPost(date: String, count: Int, id: String )
object HiringPost {

  implicit val hiringPostFormat = Json.format[HiringPost]

  implicit val hiringWrites: Writes[HiringPost] = (
    (JsPath \ "date").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "count").write[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "id").write[String]
  )(unlift(HiringPost.unapply))

  implicit val hiringReads: Reads[HiringPost] = (
    (JsPath \  "created_at").read[String] and
    (JsPath \  "num_comments").read[Int] and
    (JsPath \  "objectID").read[String]
  )(HiringPost.apply _)
}
```

but the response I am getting when trying to parse the JSON is:

```
result is: JsError(List((/hits(0)/date,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/hits(0)/count,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/hits(0)/id,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))
```

what is wrong with the way I have written the parsing or implicits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Reads` and `Writes` you don't need `Formats`.

Remove your `implicit val hiringPostFormat = Json.format[HiringPost]` and add `import HiringPost._` in your parsing class to put the implicits in scope - it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't define a `Format[HiringPost]` if you have a Reads and a Writes. I'm surprised that's not an implicit resolution error. Get rid of this line:

```
implicit val hiringPostFormat = Json.format[HiringPost]
```

You can also replace your trivial Writes implicitation with the macro `Json.writes[HiringPost]`

Comment: Do you know where I can find more info about formats versus Reads/Writes? This was really unclear to me in the Play documentation.